# How to use dynamic urls on templates

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-urls

I using python 2.7.11 and django 1.10.2. I created urls and use dynamically templates.

**urls.py**

```
url(r'^suits-anarkali/', include([
                url(r'^$', category_page, name="suits-anarkali"),
                url(r'^(?P<slug>[\w-]+)/$', category_page, name="suits-anarkali"),
                url(r'^(?P<slug>[\w-]+)/$', single_product, name='singleproduct'),
                url(r'^(?P<slug>[\w-]+)/(?P<singleproduct_slug>[\w-]+)/$', singleproduct, name="singleproduct"),
    ])
),
```

this is my url structure. If i call category_page with slug then it's working properly but when I call single_product with slug then it redirects to category page. 
I have tried lots of time but it is not working. So how to manage urls on the template?

**product.html**

```
{% if slug %}
    <a href="{% url 'singleproduct' slug detail.slug %}">{{ detail.product_name }}</a>
{% else %}
    <a href="{% url 'singleproduct' detail.slug %}">{{ detail.product_name }}</a>
{% endif %}
```

Comment: Please check our spelling before asking. I corrected two typos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

urls work on first match regexp basis, and since both lines below match exactly the same slug parameter , when you call a url with a slug, it is the `category_page` that matches first so django does not carry on to examine the next line. You need to make some changes to `category_page` to make it different from the other regexp.

```
    url(r'^(?P<slug>[\w-]+)/(?P<product>[\w-]+)/$', single_product, name='singleproduct'),
    url(r'^(?P<slug>[\w-]+)/$', category_page, name="suits-anarkali"),
```

[read more on url tag](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/templates/builtins/#now)

Comment: yes both lines below match exactly the same slug parameter. but name and views diff. so its possible to work proper. if possible then what change my code.

Comment: Yes, I just wanted to draw your attention to the problem. It's up to you to change one of them to avoid the unwanted pattern matching.

Comment: @ zumba yes sir, but i need to both url becouse category_page views display category and sub-category product_list list. And single_product view display category product details and singleproduct view display sub-category product details.